# How to convert empty XML tag with property json:Array="True" in JSON?

Tags: json, xml, xml-to-json

I am converting XML file to JSON.
Sample XML data:

```
<shifts json:Array="true"></shifts>
```

Output JSON:

```
"shifts": [
            {}
          ]
```

Expected output JSON:

```
"shifts": []
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You haven't said whether you are using some standard library for the conversion, and if so which (there are dozens, and they all do it differently), or whether you are doing the conversion "by hand".

Comment: You may try online tool. https://javadev.github.io/xml-to-json/